# Problem with define lambda function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I just stuck with the following lambda function definition in typescript. It might be a newbie question.

```js
type P = { id: string }
type F = <T>(x: T) => string
const f: F = (x: P) => x.id
f({ id: 'abc' }
```

But it kept complaining the below:

> Type '(x: P) => string' is not assignable to type 'F'.
>
> > Types of parameters 'x' and 'x' are incompatible.
> >
> > > Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'P'.

### Update #1

I just commenting the context why I need a generic function. I am doing a function to verify an input object, and each path of the object is configurable for verification like below:

```js
type Option = { path: string; isVerified: <T>(t: T) => boolean }

const verify = (obj: any, options: Option[]): boolean => {
  const results = options.map(option => {
    const { path, isVerified } = option
    return isVerified(obj[path])
  })
  return results.every(x => x)
}

type A = number
type B = string
const obj = { a: 1 as A, b: 'abc' as B }

verify(obj, [
  { path: 'a', isVerified: (x: A): boolean => x > 0 },
  { path: 'b', isVerified: (x: B): boolean => x.startsWith('a') }
])
```

### Update #2

Thanks for the 1st answer, it solved the problem listed in `Update #1`. However, `Update #1` is actually a simplified problem. In the real case, the `path` under `Option` type could be either `string` or `RegExg`, which makes the code in answer with `Paths[K]` invalid, like below:

```js
type Option = { path: string | RegExp; isVerified: <T>(t: T) => boolean }

const verify = (obj: any, options: Option[]): boolean => {
  const results = Object.keys(obj).map(k => {
    const verifiers = options
      .filter(opt =>
        typeof opt.path === 'string' ? opt.path === k : opt.path.test(k)
      )
      .map(x => x.isVerified)
    return verifiers.every(verify => verify(obj[k]))
  })

  return results.every(x => x)
}

type A = number
type B = string
const obj = { a: 1 as A, b: 'abc' as B }

verify(obj, [
  { path: 'a', isVerified: (x: A): boolean => x > 0 },
  { path: /b/, isVerified: (x: B): boolean => x.startsWith('a') }
])
```

See the [Play ground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=22#) for more details.

And It kept complaining below:

> Type '(x: number) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(t: T) => boolean'.
>
> > Types of parameters 'x' and 't' are incompatible.
> >
> > > Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do with these types? In particular, i don't understand why you'd be trying to use a generic here.

Comment: What's your intent/problem that you want to solve with those types?

Comment: It is part of a package I am writing, and the function's parameter is varing, and that's why I am using generic there.

Comment: Varying how? Your code (not your types) looks like it will only work with things of shape `{ id: string }`, and it will only output a string. Or do you want `id` to be able to be things other than a string?

Comment: @NicholasTower For the purpose of this generic function, I just added a `udpate #1` in the question, and I hope it make sense.

Comment: Since `f`'s parameter type is `P = { x: string }`, it doesn't make sense that `f` maps `x => x.id` since the parameter is declared to have a `.x` property, not a `.id` property.

Comment: @kaya3 thanks for you comments. It was a type when I try to extract the problem from my source code. Now I just updated the question, hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the example code:

```js
type P = { id: string }
type F = <T>(x: T) => string
const f: F = (x: P) => x.id
```

The type `F` is a generic function from any type `T` to `string`; so essentially, for a function to be of type `F` it must accept any type of argument. Your function `f` only accepts arguments of type `P`, so the function is not of type `F`.

---

Regarding the actual problem you're trying to solve, the real issue here is that `Option` should be a union type, because the parameter type for `isVerified` depends on the value of `path`:

```js
type Option = {
    path: 'a',
    isVerified: (t: number) => boolean
} | {
    path: 'b',
    isVerified: (t: string) => boolean
}
```

To make this union type easier to declare for a real use case (where there could be many more fields), define a type `Paths` for the objects you're verifying, and then construct `Option` as a mapped type:

```js
type Paths = { a: number, b: string }

type Option = {
  [K in keyof Paths]: {
    path: K,
    isVerified: (t: Paths[K]) => boolean
  }
}[keyof Paths]
```

Now your function call to `verify` will type-check, and will even infer the parameter types for you without you having to write explicit annotations:

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 'abc' }

// OK
verify(obj, [
  { path: 'a', isVerified: x => x > 0 },
  { path: 'b', isVerified: x => x.startsWith('a') }
])
```

Moreover, you'll get a type error (as desired) if `isVerified` has the wrong parameter type, because the `path` property narrows which type `isVerified` should have:

```js
// type error
verify(obj, [
  { path: 'a', isVerified: x => x.startsWith('a') },
  { path: 'b', isVerified: x => x > 0 }
])
```

There is one more edit you need to make - a type assertion in the `verify` function, since otherwise `isVerified` is inferred to take a parameter of type `never` (i.e. the *intersection* `number & string`):

```js
const verify = (obj: any, options: Option[]): boolean => {
  const results = options.map(option => {
    const { path, isVerified } = option

    // this line needs a type assertion
    return (isVerified as (t: Paths[typeof path]) => boolean)(obj[path])
  })
  return results.every(x => x)
}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACghsAFgZygXigbynAXFAOwFcBbAIwgCcAaKM-ZYSgSwIHMoBfAKG9EigB5MMGYB7AuizcoUANoBpKKygBrCCDEAzWAhQBdfJhmyoYPfgXUTs5sgBqVZluYQAJvgAUwfPCTJFfQBKdAA+OjExABsIOAITHk45dU0dPwNeAGMJRigANyctEClPMTIAK3w4kFoxEXECZHxhUQk5YPwySJi4sOlZbMbgKEoIZCIo4FQMOtbGgDoSODBS+ok+41MoQdzscyRaO0cWF3cuKVmGmyhrgHpbqCQ7KCjWaAIId1Q4R-BoOGQyCoc2uo2AREokk8R0KrjcOFQ3l8egC-Ag2jMemCfS60ViBCCpQqcn2iGCCSCJjBEMko3Gk2Q8wgBUoIE8AA8+uzKTxuDthmVylJsHgoABGWj0KAAcjgZEy0q4vHuQgU3BZzjZgtochMewsMrg0sODlh7nwnLQ4U54QADFxrLJ9Uh8NKyMblKaTnCLVz5ow4JQpgB1ZhITyy6UhHjk7gqtFQKiUMSUdWFLUVHV6zEuw0emHe81QS3W-3AQMhsOICNG6OOrA5xCu90m47OH3FrlQO1K8lAA)

Comment: thanks for your answer, it solved the problems. However, actually in the real case, the `path` in `Option` is either `string` or `RegExp`(see more details in `Update #2` in the question). Therefore I cannot use `Paths[K]` to indicate the type. Do you have a solution in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, well there's definitely no way to infer a union type of property names from the regex literal; are you using the regex just to match multiple named keys like a union (e.g. `/^(a|b)$/`) or do you need more regex capabilities than that (e.g. your regex which matches all property names with `b` in them)?

Comment: @keya3 I use regex not just for union, but for more complex matches. In this case I think probably I have to give up generic and just use `any`.

Comment: I see. If you don't need type-checking on the parameter type of `isVerified` and you're OK with having type annotations on the lambdas, then you can add `type Option = ... | { path: RegExp, isVerified: (t: never) => boolean }` where the `...` is the previous declaration using a mapped type. The parameter type `never` is contravariant, so it allows you to pass a function accepting any type of parameter. It will be your responsibility to make sure that your function works on an argument of any type associated with a property name that your regex matches, because tsc can't check that for you.

Comment: Using a union this way at least still gives you type-safety in the case when `path` is a string instead of a regex.

Comment: Shouldn't be `any` instead of `never`?

Comment: No, because `(t: number) => boolean` is not a subtype of `(t: any) => boolean` by the Liskov substitution principle. `number` is a subtype of `any` because if you will eat anything, and I give you a number, then you can eat it. But `number eater` isn't a subtype of `any eater` because if you need someone who eats anything, and I give you someone who only eats numbers, then your need is not fulfilled.

Comment: I see, make sense.